# document second level children replacing with javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

i have my html code like this

```
<div id="container>
  <p>a</p>
  <div>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>3</p>
  </div>
  <p>b</p>
</div>
```

my javascript:

```
const el = document.getElementById('#container');
// or using jquery
const el = $('#container');
```

now i want my el variable changed so that it becomes:

```
<div id="container>
  <p>a</p>
  <div>
    <p>1</p>
    <h6>2</h6>
  </div>
  <p>b</p>
</div>
```

I changed `<p>3</p>` to `<h6>2</h6>`. How can I achieve this using javascript or jquery?

Answer (score 1):

`$("#container div p:nth-child(2)").replaceWith("<h6>2</h6>");`

Comment: how do I do this using the el variable? I mean like el.nthChild.nthChild = <h6>2</h2> or something